# Difference between Ruby/JS instance variable scope

Tags: javascript, ruby

Trying to learn Ruby, and in a tutorial, I came across this code on this [page](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/2/):

```
class Greeter
  def initialize(name = "World")
    @name = name
  end
  def say_hi
    puts "Hi #{@name}!"
  end
  def say_bye
    puts "Bye #{@name}, come back soon."
  end
end
```

I am also told that the `@name` variable is an instance variable, and that it is scoped to ALL methods within the class (in this case, `Greeter`).   I am familiar-ish with JS, and it is getting a bit confusing with regards to scoping.  Let me clarify a bit.  Here is my understanding of the code in JS:

```
function Greeter (name){
    name = (typeof name === "undefined") ? "World" : name;

    function say_hi (name){
        alert('Hi ' + this.name);
    };

    function say_bye (name){
        alert('Bye ' + this.name + ', come back soon.');
    };
};
```

So in the ruby example, it appears there is a method called `initialize`, and I guess in ruby, they get the luxury of defining variable within the parameter?  In `initialize` it defines the var `@name`.  In the JS example, I explicitly abstract the naming of the var `name`, by declaring `this.name` to mean the name WITHIN `say_hi` & `say_bye`.  I understand this to be good coding practice, to differentiate the scoping, even though in this case `name` remains the same throughout the code, being either "World" if an empty parameter is passed, or the name of the person passed as a parameter. Either way, I am unsure of how the scoping works in Ruby, as I am not aware that this is possible in JS.  Take the above JS code, and compare it to :

```
function Greeter (name){

    function say_hi (name){
        this.name = (typeof name === "undefined") ? "World" : name;
        alert('Hi ' + this.name);
    };

    function say_bye (name){
        this.name = (typeof name === "undefined") ? "World" : name;
        alert('Bye ' + this.name + ', come back soon.');
    };
};
```

If I failed to declare the `this.name` in the sub-methods, it could mean the `Greeter` class variable `name`, not the `say_hi` or `say_bye` variables `name` respectively.

Questions:

1 - is the `@` in `@name` required to gain the capability to be visible to ALL methods within the class, or is this convention?  If it is convention, what does `@` signify? (I am equating this to a variable declared as `$this` in JQuery, where it signifies that the variable is a JQuery element, different from when you query by `$('whatever')`)

2 - Is the method `initialize` acting like a getter/setter method scoped within the `Greeter` class?

3 - Any other comments about your assumptions of my logic, code and questions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is roughly the same as `this` in javascript, it refers to the current instance. The `initialize` method in a class is a constructor, not a getter/setter.

```
function Greeter( name ) { 
    /*Functions called with `new` return objects
     with their proto link pointing to the object
     pointed at function's .prototype property at the time of instanciation. */
    this.name = arguments.length < 1 ? "World" : name; //No real way to do optional arguments
}

Greeter.prototype.say_hi = function() {
    alert( "Hi " + this.name + "!" ); //Methods are defined outside on the `.prototype` object
};

Greeter.prototype.say_bye = function() {
    alert( "Bye " + this.name + ", come back soon." );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `@` is a must to declare `@name` as an instance variable, as `{name : 'foo'}` in js;
2. `initialize` acts like `Constructor` in `new Constructor(foo, bar)` in js. When `new Constructor(foo, bar)`, ruby will call `Constructor#initialize` with arguments `foo` and `bar`.

I think it is not the best to compare js with ruby; ruby is class based OOP, which is similar to C++ and Java.

Comment: js and ruby are both OOP. js is a prototype based OOP, ruby is a class based OOP.